# Setblock at a Player's Location with Command Blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make it so you place a dispenser at the nearest player's location (if the nearest player is not available, than I could just use me). I can't just make the coordinates `~ ~ ~` because I'm using this command from a command block, and that would just place the block at the location of the command block. Here is what I've got so far:

```
/setblock (this is where I need help) minecraft:dispenser 2 keep {Items:[{id:35, Slot:0, Count:-1,Data:0}]}
```

Most of the command is specific to what I need to do, the basic form of this is:

```
/setblock (this is where I need help) minecraft:dispenser 2
```

Answer (score 3):

The full command you want should be this:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:dispenser 2 keep {Items:[{id:35, Slot:0, Count:-1,Data:0}]}
```

The "execute" command takes a selector, a set of coordinates, and another command. It runs that other command as if the selected entity was running it. For example:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /say hello
```

Would make the closest player say "hello", even if a command block or another player is actually running the command above.

Comment: You main want to change `~ ~ ~` to `~ ~-1 ~` as to not place the block inside the player.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute at @p run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ ...` (the syntax for the items in the dispenser would also need 1.13-ification, but I'm not going to bother doing it since it is not relevant to the question.